# How to export MS IAS Radius Login Events to a remote system

Tags: logging, radius, windows-ias-server

Is there a way to (export|pull) MS IAS radius login events (to|from) a remote system ?

I can see that the logs are stored in plain text in a file called

system32/logfiles/nap

On the Windows 2008 server.

Am I right in saying that these logs can't be accessed by querying the windows event log ?

Pls excuse my ignorance of windows etc, I more a linux/FreeBSB person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shared this folder and used a program called "IAS Log Viewer" to view the RAS log.